# Recursion-schemes generalization of `tails`

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I've got a recursion-schemes style structure and I'd like to obtain a list of all substructures including the full structure - i.e. the equivalent of what the `tails` function does on a `List`. I think it would be possible to implement this by calling `para`, mapping back to the original structure at each step, and then sticking the original structure on the front separately, but that seems very cumbersome: (untested, apologies if the Haskell is incorrect; written in terms of `Mu` as I haven't really understood the `Base` construct yet)

```
gtails :: Functor f => Mu f -> [Mu f]
gtails = para (\a -> (fmap fst a) : (foldMap snd a))
```

(i.e. in the case `f=Prim` this is `tails`, for other `f` it's a generalization)

Is there a nicer way? I realise this isn't so bad, but the `fmap fst a` to recover the "original" structure at that step feels quite cumbersome, and the `foldMap snd a` is something I find myself repeating a lot when using `para` (likewise `fold a` when using `cata` which again feels like it should be unnecessary).

Answer (score 10):

I don't see any issue with `para`. Just cons back the head and the tail at each `Cons` step:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = para (\case Nil -> [[]]; Cons a (as, res) -> (a : as) : res)
```

For clarity, specialized to lists and without `recursion-schemes`:

```
para :: (a -> [a] -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
para f z []     = z
para f z (a:as) = f a as (para f z as)

tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = para (\a as res -> (a : as) : res) [[]]
```

However, if you'd like to be more general, the less nice `para` formulation comes handy:

```
import qualified Data.Functor.Foldable as Rec (Foldable)

tails :: (Rec.Foldable t, Base t ~ Prim [a]) => t -> [t]
tails as = as : para (\case Nil -> []; Cons a (as, res) -> as : res) as
```

This works for lists as usual, but you can also give `type instance Base t = Prim [a]` for other `t`-s, along with the `Foldable` instance, and use them as well.

Alternatively, we can keep the first `tails` definition at the cost of introducing an `Unfoldable` constraint:

```
tails' :: (Unfoldable t, Rec.Foldable t, Base t ~ Prim [a]) => t -> [t]
tails' = para (\case Nil -> [embed Nil]; Cons a (as, res) -> embed (Cons a as) : res)
```

This isn't too bad, since for each `project` there should be an inverse `embed` for fixpoints of functors anyway, so the `Foldable` and `Unfoldable` instances naturally come in pairs.

Comment: I need a version in terms of recursion-schemes because my actual case is not `List` but a recursion-schemes style structure. AIUI the recursion-schemes `para` is `para :: Foldable t => (Base t (t, a) -> a) -> t -> a` which doesn't have the `b` parameter from your example. Can you give a version in terms of this `para` (or other recursion-schemes code) that is `tails` if we call it with `t f a = Maybe (a, f)` (in the sense that `Base t` is then isomorphic to `List`, unless I'm mistaken) but can also be called with other `t`?

Comment: `Prim` seems to be a `List`-specific thing, whereas I want a version that works for non-list data structures, and I don't think I necessarily could always define a `Base t ~ Prim [a]`? The function I'm thinking of shouldn't need any additional constraints - I've updated the question with an implementation that I think would be valid (but which I'd expect to be a standard function, or at least more concise than my version).

Answer (score 1):

`para` is indeed the right function to use here. I have put everything in a [self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/4b0671fee50923320cbf) augmented with examples if you want to play with it.

We start with the definition of the fixpoint `Mu` and the usual `fold` and `para`.

```
module Tails where

import Data.Function

newtype Mu f = In { out :: f (Mu f) }

fold :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Mu f -> a
fold alg = alg . fmap (fold alg) . out

para :: Functor f => (f (a, Mu f) -> a) -> Mu f -> a
para alg = alg . fmap (\m -> (para alg m, m)). out
```

We can then implement `tails` using `para` and an additional `Foldable` constraint allowing us to use `foldMap` to collect the intermediate result in the list monoid:

```
tails :: (Functor f, Foldable f) => Mu f -> [Mu f]
tails m = m : para (foldMap $ uncurry $ flip (:)) m
```

Comment: Is this the preferred style when using `para` then? I thought of doing the recursion this way around, but I don't like the `m :` any more than I like the `fmap fst` - either way it feels like slightly the wrong abstraction.